# What is this clover-like plant with a thick woody root system?

Tags: identification

[image]
This plant is growing all over the place in one part of the garden. I'm wondering whether to try to get rid of it completely, or just reduce it - but I'd like to know what it is.

It seems to have a very well established root system. (some kind of tuber I think, see image below).

I've attached photos. (It's just sprouting at the moment - normally a lot bigger.)

I'm in Central Europe.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I think that is a [columbine](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=columbine%20plant%20wikipedia&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQjBAwAg&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquilegia_canadensis&ei=st2ET_iqLYTw0gG2hr3NBw&v6u=http://dualstack.ipv6-exp.l.google.com/gen_204?ip=174.59.243.98&ts=1334107507017583&auth=g5witf3lwmymauig7e7wyzuwywdvsvkx&rndm=0.7430487170349807&v6s=2&v6t=51908&usg=AFQjCNEEBjSdRpAh57qPLtGQ3Iq5IDm18w). I have them blooming in my gardens. They can have quite variable leaf form, but I am pretty sure from your plant and leaf photos that this is it. They get up to three feet tall, and grow in moist rich soil from full shade to near full sun. The flowers are extremely variable, but usually appear in mid-spring on the tops of the stems, hanging down.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks - Certainly looks similar. I'll wait until it flowers and post a follow up, before deciding its fate!